# What is the best way to create feathers for a model so that the model does not slow down game in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: texturing, rigging, particles, unreal-engine, optimization

Please tell me the solution. I'm creating a bird-man model in Blender for a game that will be on Unreal Engine 5. It comes down to the feathers. What method should be used to create them so that the model does not load the game too much, while the feathers look realistic? Is it possible to do this using particles?
I was advised to create a feather and use an instance object to distribute the feathers across the surface of the model. However, I don't know how to create the feather itself? Should I do this with particles or use an image as a texture?
I would like to create a high-quality and optimized model for the game.

Comment: An image with transparency would be lighter than a mesh, do you have reference images of a birdman?

Comment: This [example of a parrot](https://youtu.be/8yoIW4va-VY?) shows how to create these image planes for the feathers. It's kinda particles baked into an image. They are similar to so-called hair cards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an image texture. You could have several variations of feather in one 512/512 image aligned in a grid formation, cut them into separate plains that share the same material, seperate each one into separate objects with the origin at the base of the feather, add them all to a new collection, and make a particle system using the new collection on yout wing object.

You could even include several feathers in one square of your grid image to save on the number of planes in your particle system.

For realism, you can bake normal, roughness, and maybe shean maps from the base color image.